# how to get the comma separated values of the column stored in the Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

how to get the comma separated values stored in the Sql Db into a individual values

e.g in sql DB the column is stored with comma values as shown below,

```
EligibleGroup

A11,A12,A13
B11,B12,B13
```

I need to get

```
EligibleGroup

A11
A12
A13
B11
B12
...
```

I have written a query that will fetch me some list of employees with employee name and eligible group

```
XXX  A11
YYY  B11
ZZZ  C11
```

I need to check that the employees(XXX,YYY,ZZZ) eligiblegroup falls within this

```
EligibleGroup

A11,A12,A13
B11,B12,B13
```

and return me only that rows.

Answer (score 1):

use a "user defined function" like the one shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL_UDF_to_Parse_a_String.aspx) (including source code) - it returns the splitted values as a "table" (one row per value) you can select from like

```
select txt_value from dbo.fn_ParseText2Table('A11,A12,A13')
```

returns

```
A11
A12
A13
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT employee_name, eligible_group 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE eligible_group IN 
        (SELECT SPLIT(EligibleGroup) 
         FROM tblEligibleGroup 
         WHERE <some conditions here>)
```

I don't believe the "SPLIT" function exists in SQL Server so you'll have to either create a user defined function to handle that, or you could use the nifty workaround suggested here: [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

Comment: I think OP is actually looking for someone to provide the split function, not so much to be told that he needs one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `EligibleGroup` has a fixed length data, you can try using [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) As follows:

```
select substring(EligibleGroup,1,3) from @test union all
select substring(EligibleGroup,5,3) from @test union all
select substring(EligibleGroup,9,3) from @test
```

This will return:

```
A11
A12
A13
B11
B12
...
```

You can try it in [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2166/get-comma-separated-of-a-fixed-length-data)

And If you need to check if an employee fall into which `EligibleGroup` try this:

```
Select EligibleGroup from test where eligibleGroup like '%A11'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not have to split EligibleGroup. You can do another way by just:

```
select empId
from yourTempEmpTable t1, EligibleGroup t2
where t2.elibigle like '%'+t1.elibigle+'%'
```

I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way,

select  left('A11,A12,A13',3) +  SUBSTRING('A11,A12,A13',charindex(',','A11,A12,A13'),10)